# How to convert angled edges to right angles

Tags: algorithm

I have a shape that looks like this image:

[image]

Assuming I have all the points of the vertices how would I go about converting the object on the left to the right?

Comment: First, find angles between vertices which are significantly different from a right angle.

Comment: @AndrewMorton thanks right now I'm finding the angles between each vertice and then I check the angle using (angle mod 90 = 0) if it's 0 then they are right angles so I skip those if not then (This is where I think I mess up) I create two points using the vertices. P1 = (x1,y2) P2 = (y2,x1) not sure where to go from here since what I have currently isn't displaying the correct results. I was thinking of checking if the points in the polygon but that doesn't work for the concave ones.

Comment: 1) It would be a good idea to edit your question to include the steps you've taken so far, perhaps with a bit of relevant code. 2) That `(angle mod 90 = 0)` looks to be too strict for the wobbly angle at the bottom-left.

Comment: You flagged this as `vb.net`, but I don't think you're ready to start worrying about language-specific implementation details. Can you update the question with more details about what you've already tried, and with a more explicit specification of the behavior you're trying to accomplish? Right now we don't even have enough details to discuss algorithms.

Comment: If you don't have scattered points (the vertices are already *ordered* clock-wise, the world coordinates are already rotated and aligned to the reference vector (i.e., the two *points* that draw the first *line*) you can assume the when two points have  `X₁≈ X₂` or `Y₁≈ Y₂`, the next change will be in the opposite direction. e.g., assume the *top* line has points `(0, 0):(100,0)`, `Y` doesn't change, so the next variation must be in `Y` and `X` should not change. If `X` changes, it determines (± the previous value) the direction. You can change the next point `± X` value to match the previous.

Comment: If you add all modified points to a GraphicsPath (assuming you can use this tool), it will connect the *orphaned* vertices for you (you can then extract the point generated or and transformations to the *path*). Otherwise, if it's enough, add the missing points yourself.

Comment: Sorry I should probably be posting this in an algorithm specific area. Is there one? The points are organized clock wise already. I'm currently looping through all points and comparing the angles as suggested above. If they are not 90 degrees then I take P1 x1 y2 and P2 x2 y1 and check which is in the polygon if it's not then I set the current point to that and then continue my loop until all are 90 degrees. Sorry I can't post code right now I am in the gym

Comment: @Jimi I think you helped me figure it out. I completely forgot that if it's doing right angles then x or y must stay constant. I'll try to implement it when I get back from the weekend and I'll mark yours as an answer if it works. Thanks

Comment: *The points are organized clock wise already.* You should edit your question and add such detail. If this is the case, seems you are on the right track and it is really unclear what you are seeking help for.

Comment: I think Jimi identified one of the key elements but missed one I also consider essential, that is that in the end since all of the angles will be right angles, then all of the lines will be parallel or perpendicular to one line, which you could call the primary axis, and the axis can be rotated. I don't think of this as a graphics problem but as a term rewrite problem. In other words, Jimi is looking at the problem from the start going forward, but if you look at it from the end going backwards it also adds information that is of value.

Comment: @Guy Coder You got me there :) *"I don't think of this as a graphics problem"*: well, this is what I do think of first, I'm probably stuck in that mindset. This mindset also determined the first part of my comment (*ordering of the vectors*, *rotation of the plane*). So, the suggestion is probably related to the two-pass algorithm, an application of the Connected-component labeling algorithm, in the Graph theory realm. You can understand that, in this context (component labeling, linked lists etc.), back-tracking is not exactly what you would do.

Comment: @Jimi Hi there, still having a little troubles understanding this algorithm. I realized that the shape will be rotated at times so X₁≈ X₂ or Y₁≈ Y₂ doesn't necessarily work when the object is rotated. The points are organized counter clockwise still but I'm having trouble figuring out what I need to do next.

Comment: I was able to get something to work but it won't work for all cases here are my steps.

1. Gather all points (counter clockwise)
2. Loop through all points.
3. Compare current and next point's rotation using Angle MOD 90.
4. Draw 4 lines 2 perpendicular and 2 parallel from each point.
5. Check the intersection points and add a vertex at the one's that are outside the polygon.
6. This doesn't work when edges are concave due to the Point In Polygon check that I use in step 5.
7. Trying to figure out now how to make this work for concave edges as well.